# Remove software and PPA's entirely

Tags: ubuntu, apt, elementary-os, ppa

I have a lot of software installed, from various sources, and I would like to start using Flatpaks instead of PPA's. But how do I remove my current software entirely, with the PPA's and such? This is the output from my `sudo apt update` (I am using elementary os based on ubuntu 16.04

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                               
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:6 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bablu-boy/nutty-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                             
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                
Hit:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/vapoursynth/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                             
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                    
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                       
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                       
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                        
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                  
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                             
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                               
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                       
Hit:19 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease                                              
Hit:21 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy InRelease                                                    
Hit:22 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
```

Let's say, I want to remove Blender, MonoDevelop and LibreOffice entirely, so I could install it via Flatpaks later. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge "packagename"
```

Then go through the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory and remove any file referencing that repo.

Also go through `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `sources.list~` with `sudo vi` or `sudo nano` and remove or comment out the repository.

Finally remove the GPG key for that repository

```
sudo apt-key list

sudo apt-key del #A#A#A
```